# Looping through files in a dir; Pulling out filenames to replace string(s) in existing files

Tags: linux, bash, macos, scripting

I have a directory of markdown files that I'm trying to accomplish the following with:

- Grab the filename of the markdown file and store it in a variable
- Take that variable and replace a series of strings in the file with the stored filename variable
- loop through all of the files in the directory and do the same thing

I'm close, but the following code is pulling out the filename of only the first markdown file and applying the variable to all strings in the files. Here's my working code so far:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in /home/user/dir/*; do

  str="somestring"
  filename=$(basename $file)
  fn="$(echo "${filename%.*}")"

  find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/${str}/${fn}/g" {} \;

done
```

Assuming that the markdown file looks like this:

`123456789.md` and is at `/home/user/dir/123456789.md` with several other .md files with other, random numerical names.

Structure of the .md files is similar to:

```
---
layout: default
date: 2010-03-28
original: /orig/somestring.jpg
thumbnail: /thumb/somestring_thumb.jpg
permalink: /images/somestring/
---
```

and my goal would be for the script to make each file look like this, based on the filename of the .md file itself:

```
---
layout: default
date: 2010-03-28
original: /orig/123456789.jpg
thumbnail: /thumb/123456789_thumb.jpg
permalink: /images/123456789/
---
```

Any thoughts on the best way to edit the sed call, or another way to write this? Occasionally in my testing, sed was returning `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`, but was going through with the rename of the string anyway, even if it was the wrong string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the following would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /home/user/dir/*; do

    str="somestring"
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    fn=${filename%.*}

    LANG=C sed -i '' -e "s/${str}/${fn}/g" "$file"

done
```

The problem is you are executing `find & sed` in the `for` loop, which overreplace strings in unrelated files.
`LANG=C` prior to `sed` would be a common workaround for `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` problem.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. That works great to solve my problem. Is there a better way to write this without a `for` loop that would do the same thing?

Comment: You could probably do it with `find` and `exec` or `xargs` but `for` seems more straightforward.  https://www.everythingcli.org/find-exec-vs-find-xargs/

Answer (score 1):

Consider utilizing the following solution which is fairly robust. It ensures any character, in either your given search string and/or Markdown filename that may be interpreted as a [basic regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) (BRE) metacharacter,  is treated as a literal in the `sed` replacement.

#### Solution:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

target_dir=/path/to/dir
search='somestring'

search_escaped=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$search")

while read -rd ''; do
  base=$(basename -- "$REPLY")
  replace_escaped=$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<<"${base%.*}")
  sed -i '' -e 's/'"$search_escaped"'/'"$replace_escaped/g"'' "$REPLY"
done < <(find $target_dir -depth 1 -type f -name '*.md' -print0)
```

**Explanation:**

- The value for the `target_dir` variable should be defined as the pathname of the directory that you want to perform a search in. For instance `/home/user/dir` as specified in your question.
- The value of the `search` variable should be changed to the string that you want to search for in your markdown (`.md`) files, and it must be enclosed in single quotes (`'...'`).
- The line that reads;

  ```bash
  search_escaped=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$search")
  ```

  escapes potential BRE metacharacters that may exist in your `search` string and assigns the result to a new variable named `search_escaped`.

  We do this because ultimately the search string that you define will be used as the *search* string with sed's [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command), i.e. *`s/regexp/replacement/flags`*. Essentially each character of your given `search` string is placed in its own character set `[...]` expression to treat it as a literal, except for caret (`^`) character(s) as they get escaped as `\^`. Refer to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed#answer-29613573) for further details.

  This means we can provide a `search` string, such as `s$o.m *e[s\t^ring`, i.e. one with many metacharacters, and they will treated as literals, and prevent our program from going awry.
- Using the [`find`](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) utility we define the following command to obtain the pathname of all `.md` files within the given `target_dir`:

  ```bash
  find $target_dir -depth 1 -type f -name '*.md' -print0
  ```

  - The `-depth 1` part ensures we only find files at the top level. However if you  want to recursively descend the given directory tree you can remove it - by removing it you'll also include any `.md` files in the sub-directories of the given directory many levels deep.
  - The `-name '*.md'` part ensures that we only include the Markdown files (`.md`) and exclude any other files which may exist in the given `target_dir`.
  - The `find` part enclosed in `<( ... )` which is referred to as [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution), and the preceding `<` [redirects](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) the pathnames found by `find` to `stdin`.
- The `while` loop [read](https://ss64.com/osx/read.html)s the results of the the `find` command, i.e. pathnames of each `.md` file found.

  In the body of the `while` loop we carry out the following tasks:

  - We obtain the *basename* from each pathname (Note: `$REPLY` is an inbuilt variable associated with `while` - in this scenario it holds a reference to a pathname during each turn of the loop):

    ```js
    base=$(basename -- "$REPLY")
    ```
  - The line that reads:

    ```js
    replace_escaped=$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<<"${base%.*}")
    ```

    escapes what may be perceived by `sed` as a placeholder character such as `\1` in the filename. For example; if a file was named `somefile\1\2\3.md` that would fail when we replace the `search` string with it - however this safeguards against that. Again, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed#answer-29613573) for further details.

    The `${base%.*}` part utilizes [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to omit the file extension part (i.e. `.md`) from the value of the `base` variable (i.e. from the filename/basename).
  - Finally, we replace all instances of the *search* string (i.e. the value of the `$search_escaped` variable) that may exist in the Markdown file with the value of the `replace_escaped` variable (i.e. the filename without the file extension).

    ```js
    sed -i '' -e 's/'"$search_escaped"'/'"$replace_escaped/g"'' "$REPLY"
    ```

---

<sub>**Known issue:** It's possible for any part of a basename to include newline characters (`\n`), and whilst this solution does correctly handle the discovery of such a pathname using methods described [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) - It does not currently perform the string replacement when the filename contains newline characters.</sub>

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. This seems like an excellent way to do it.